# EF4: mapping to an "Extra Fields" table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have two tables:

TICKET

- GUID (PK)
- there are other columns not related to this question

TICKET_PROPERTIES

- GUID (partial PK, FK to TICKET.GUID)
- FIELDNAME (partial PK)
- FIELDVALUE

If I have these ticket records:

- { GUID = "my_ticket" }
- { GUID = "my_ticket_2" }

Then I could possibly have some TICKET_PROPERTIES records like:

- { GUID = "my_ticket", FIELDNAME = "FieldA", FIELDVALUE = "value a" }
- { GUID = "my_ticket", FIELDNAME = "FieldB", FIELDVALUE = "foo" }
- { GUID = "my_ticket", FIELDNAME = "FieldC", FIELDVALUE = "bar" }
- { GUID = "my_ticket_2", FIELDNAME = "FieldC", FIELDVALUE = "blah" }
- { GUID = "my_ticket_2", FIELDNAME = "FieldD", FIELDVALUE = "data" }

As you can see, this TICKET_PROPERTIES table serves as an "extra fields" table for fields that a TICKET record can optionally have.  A TICKET may not always have an associated TICKET_PROPERTIES record with FIELDNAME="FieldA", but sometimes they do.

If I wanted to add a FieldA property to my TICKET class in this EDMX file, how could I do it?
It would be nice if such a property could build a where condition into the query generated by something like this:

```
MINE_EF_TestContext ctx = new MINE_EF_TestContext();
var someTickets = ctx.TICKET.Where(t => t.FieldA == "value a");
```

I would like to be able to add more than one property like this.  For example I would probably want to be able to add a FieldB property as well.

My EDMX:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
<edmx:Runtime>
<edmx:StorageModels>
<Schema Namespace="MINE_EF_Test.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="EFOracleProvider" ProviderManifestToken="11g" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
  <EntityContainer Name="MINE_EF_TestStoreContainer">
    <EntitySet Name="TICKET" EntityType="MINE_EF_Test.Store.TICKET" store:Type="Tables" />
    <EntitySet Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES" EntityType="MINE_EF_Test.Store.TICKET_PROPERTIES" store:Type="Tables" />
    <AssociationSet Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK" Association="MINE_EF_Test.Store.TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK">
      <End Role="TICKET" EntitySet="TICKET" />
      <End Role="TICKET_PROPERTIES" EntitySet="TICKET_PROPERTIES" />
    </AssociationSet>
  </EntityContainer>
  <EntityType Name="TICKET">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="GUID" Type="varchar2" Nullable="false" MaxLength="36" />
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="FIELDNAME" />
      <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="FIELDNAME" Type="varchar2" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" />
    <Property Name="FIELDVALUE" Type="varchar2" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1000" />
    <Property Name="GUID" Type="varchar2" Nullable="false" MaxLength="36" />
  </EntityType>
  <Association Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK">
    <End Role="TICKET" Type="MINE_EF_Test.Store.TICKET" Multiplicity="1" />
    <End Role="TICKET_PROPERTIES" Type="MINE_EF_Test.Store.TICKET_PROPERTIES" Multiplicity="*" />
    <ReferentialConstraint>
      <Principal Role="TICKET">
        <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
      </Principal>
      <Dependent Role="TICKET_PROPERTIES">
        <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
      </Dependent>
    </ReferentialConstraint>
  </Association>
  <Association Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK_POC">
    <End Role="TICKET" Type="MINE_EF_Test.Store.TICKET" Multiplicity="0..1" />
    <End Role="TICKET_PROPERTIES" Type="MINE_EF_Test.Store.TICKET_PROPERTIES" Multiplicity="1" />
    <ReferentialConstraint>
      <Principal Role="TICKET_PROPERTIES">
        <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
      </Principal>
      <Dependent Role="TICKET">
        <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
      </Dependent>
    </ReferentialConstraint>
  </Association>
</Schema>
</edmx:StorageModels>
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
<Schema Namespace="MINE_EF_Test" Alias="Self" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
  <EntityContainer Name="MINE_EF_TestContext" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
    <EntitySet Name="TICKET" EntityType="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET" />
    <EntitySet Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES" EntityType="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET_PROPERTIES" />
    <AssociationSet Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK" Association="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK">
      <End Role="TICKET" EntitySet="TICKET" />
      <End Role="TICKET_PROPERTIES" EntitySet="TICKET_PROPERTIES" />
    </AssociationSet>
  </EntityContainer>
  <EntityType Name="TICKET">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="GUID" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="36" Unicode="false" FixedLength="false" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES" Relationship="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK" FromRole="TICKET" ToRole="TICKET_PROPERTIES" />
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="FIELDNAME" />
      <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="FIELDNAME" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" Unicode="false" FixedLength="false" />
    <Property Name="FIELDVALUE" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1000" Unicode="false" FixedLength="false" />
    <Property Name="GUID" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="36" Unicode="false" FixedLength="false" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="TICKET" Relationship="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK" FromRole="TICKET_PROPERTIES" ToRole="TICKET" />
  </EntityType>
  <Association Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK">
    <End Role="TICKET" Type="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET" Multiplicity="1" />
    <End Role="TICKET_PROPERTIES" Type="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET_PROPERTIES" Multiplicity="*" />
    <ReferentialConstraint>
      <Principal Role="TICKET">
        <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
      </Principal>
      <Dependent Role="TICKET_PROPERTIES">
        <PropertyRef Name="GUID" />
      </Dependent>
    </ReferentialConstraint>
  </Association>
</Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
<edmx:Mappings>
<Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs">
  <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="MINE_EF_TestStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="MINE_EF_TestContext">
    <EntitySetMapping Name="TICKET">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="TICKET">
          <ScalarProperty Name="GUID" ColumnName="GUID" />
          </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <EntitySetMapping Name="TICKET_PROPERTIES">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET_PROPERTIES">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="TICKET_PROPERTIES">
          <ScalarProperty Name="FIELDNAME" ColumnName="FIELDNAME" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="FIELDVALUE" ColumnName="FIELDVALUE" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="GUID" ColumnName="GUID" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    </EntityContainerMapping>
</Mapping>
</edmx:Mappings>
</edmx:Runtime>
<edmx:Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
<Connection><DesignerInfoPropertySet><DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" /></DesignerInfoPropertySet></Connection>
<edmx:Options />
<edmx:Diagrams >
      <Diagram Name="MINE_EF_Test" ZoomLevel="96">
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="1.125" Height="1.4033821614583335" IsExpanded="true" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET_PROPERTIES" Width="1.5" PointX="2.75" PointY="1.25" Height="1.787985026041667" IsExpanded="true" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="MINE_EF_Test.TICKET_PROPERTIES_TICKET_FK" ManuallyRouted="false">
          <ConnectorPoint PointX="2.25" PointY="1.8891910807291668" />
          <ConnectorPoint PointX="2.75" PointY="1.8891910807291668" />
        </AssociationConnector>
      </Diagram>
    </edmx:Diagrams>
</edmx:Designer></edmx:Edmx>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current EF version doesn't offer mapping records from related table to parent entity properties. Moreover this scenario requires dynamic properties because you can have different number of related record with different names.

You must use this approach:

```
MINE_EF_TestContext ctx = new MINE_EF_TestContext();
var someTickets = from t in ctx.Tickets
                  join p in ctx.Properties on t.Guid equals p.Guid
                  where p.FieldName == "FieldA" && p.FieldValue == "value a"
                  select t;
```